# About ODE $2p'q-3pq'=\lambda$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to give any possible characterization (could be geometric, algebraic or of other type) of a pair of functions $p$ and $q$, holomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$, and a complex number $\lambda$ satisfying the ODE
$$2p'q-3pq'=\lambda$$

In an algebraic point of view since every holomorphic function is analytic we can write $p(z) = \sum_{i \geq 0}a_i z^i$ and $q(z) = \sum_{j \geq 0}b_j z^j$ so replacing $p$, $q$ and their derivatives in the expression we get:

$$2p'q-3pq'= \sum_{k\geq 1}[\sum_{i+j = k}2ia_ib_j-3ja_ib_j] x^{k-1} = \lambda$$

which clearly implies

\begin{cases}
    2a_1b_0 - 3a_0b_1 = \lambda\\
    \sum_{i+j=k}2ia_i-3ja_ib_j &= 0 \quad (\forall k \geq 2)
  \end{cases}

This question is not just looking for an explicit solution (since it could be more difficult than expected) but regarding some information or knowledge about the set of solutions. Also, if you have some recommendations of papers or books in which similar equations are treated (maybe in fields like ODEs or Dynamic systems), that would also be helpful... All help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

*Too long for a comment.*

If $p$ and $q$ are holomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$, then $f:=pq$ also is holomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$. Using $q=f/p$, you can eliminate it from the equation $2p'q-3pq'=\lambda$, thus obtaining
$$
5\frac{p'f}{p}-3f'=\lambda, \tag{1}
$$
whose solution is
$$
p(z)=[f(z)]^{3/5}\exp\left(\frac{\lambda}{5}\int\frac{dz}{f(z)}\right). \tag{2}
$$
Now try to characterize $f$ so that both $p$ and $q$ are holomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$. For instance, $f(z)=a\,(a\neq 0)$ is OK, as it implies
$$
p(z)=c\exp\left(\frac{\lambda z}{5a}\right)\quad\text{and}\quad
q(z)=\frac{a}{c}\exp\left(-\frac{\lambda z}{5a}\right)\quad(c\neq 0). \tag{3}
$$
On the other hand, $f(z)=az\,(a\neq 0)$ is not OK in general, as it implies
$$
p(z)=cz^{\left(\frac{3}{5}+\frac{\lambda}{5a}\right)}\quad\text{and}\quad
q(z)=\frac{a}{c}z^{\left(\frac{2}{5}-\frac{\lambda}{5a}\right)}\quad(c\neq 0). \tag{4}
$$
There are only two values of $a$ for which both $p$ and $q$ are holomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$: (1) $a=-\frac{\lambda}{3}$, in which case $p(z)=c$ and $q(z)=-\frac{\lambda z}{3c}$, and (2) $a=\frac{\lambda}{2}$, in which case $p(z)=cz$ and $q(z)=\frac{\lambda}{2c}$.